# SQLite Exception query error

Tags: android, sqlite

can someone tell me if this is correct please?

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = ("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                                            COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ 
                                            COLUMN_TITLE + "text not null," + 
                                            COLUMN_CATEGORY + "text not null," + 
                                            COLUMN_IMAGE + "text not null);");
```

the error is SQLiteException

Answer (score 4):

You are missing space between columns and table name. Here is corrected query:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
 COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ 
 COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null," + 
 COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null," + 
 COLUMN_IMAGE + " text not null);");
```

Also, take care about semi-colon at the end of query. It's very problematic - i mean on some devices this symbol may cause error (safer is to don't use it).

Hope i helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: where exactly shall i put the space?

Answer (score 2):

```
COLUMN_TITLE + "text not null" this is your mistake,
```

Add a space at your column's data type like below,

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = ("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                                            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ 
                                            COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null," + 
                                            COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null," + 
                                            COLUMN_IMAGE + " text not null);");
```

You were missing a space between your column name and its data type.

Comment: what is exactly the mistake please?